# Using jQuery or Javascript redirect to given page with a value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown, on its change it should redirect to a page with the dropdown's value say as a POST

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('some_dropdown').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var datastring = 'id=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                window.location.href("xyz.php");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On the xyz.php page:

```
if ($_POST['id']) {
    Blah Blah..
}
```

It's not recognizing that **id** value on the xyz page. I want it's value on the redirected page.

Edited - To make things more clear, I tried out to print the xyz.php's contents on my original page (instead of redirecting) like this -

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".somediv").html(html);
            }
```

FYI, "somediv" was `<div class="somediv"></div>` in my original page(no-redirecting) and it worked!! It could identify the `id`. Some how **can't work** it out with redirecting. It can't identify the `id`.

Edited --

Last thing, if I don't redirect and use

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".somediv").html(html);
            }
```

The data loads perfect, my question is can I make some changes in the dynamically loaded textboxes and insert them in the database

Comment: I just want to redirect with a value in hand, That's all

Comment: @Zerocode what does dropdown look like? Is it simple `<select>` or not?

Comment: Yea a simple dropdown, values are generated from the database..simple HTML written `<select>`

Comment: What are you want to do from this code ? I don't understand why you are posting data to xyz.php and immediately redirect to the same file right after.

Comment: @Bang, I want to go to xyz.php on dropdown change with dropdown's value in hand! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to make a post request can make it by appending a virtual form.
Here is the code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('[name="some_dropdown"]').change(function() {
                var mval = $(this).val(); //takes the value from dropdown
                var url = 'xyz.php'; //the page on which value is to be sent
  //the virtual form with input text, value and name to be submitted
                var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">'+
                        '<input type="text" name="id" value="' + mval + '" />'+
                        '</form>');
                $('body').append(form); //append to the body
                form.submit(); //submit the form and the page redirects
            });
        });
```

and on PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `datastring` should be `key value` pair. Like this.

```
var datastring = {'id':id};
```

Comment: Please remove this line `window.location.href= "xyz.php?"+datastring+"";
` and add `console.log(html)`

Comment: @void data **can** be `String`, being query string. If you pass `Object` as data, it is transformed into query string.

Comment: void you want to remove `window.location.href("xyz.php");
` and type `console.log(html)` ?

Comment: Exactly.. Just do it once and see what prints in the console (It should print what you PHP file echos, So make sure to echo something in your PHP).

Comment: @void, console is undefined, I used alert to echo out something, and it did show me the value I wanted, after commenting `window.location.href("xyz.php");`. Now how to go on xyz.php

Comment: Do `echo $_POST["id"]` in your xyz.php. And when the ajax success it should get stores inside `html`. Check whether it is in console or not.

Answer (score 0):

you have few mistakes in your code so your correct code will be like this

```
$('.some_dropdown').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var datastring = 'id='+id;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xyz.php",
    data: datastring,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    window.location.href= "xyz.php?"+datastring+"";
     }
  });
```

});
});

and php code

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    Blah Blah..
}
```

Comment: I edited php code and have you checked that it alerts `id` or not ?

Comment: @Afaan don't you ever see dropdowns, that look good and are not made of simple `<select>`? Nevertheless, I've got confirmation from OP in question's comments.